# Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" | pub get failed

Tags: flutter

I upgraded my flutter to `3.7.9` and ager that i am trying to create a new flutter app using `flutter create appname` but getting below error. I think this is due to dart and flutter conflict. Anyone faced the same?

```
Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "/Users/xxx/flutter/bin/cache/pkg/sky_engine".
pub get failed
command: "/Users/xxx/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart __deprecated_pub --color --directory gauramarg get --example"
pub env: {
  "FLUTTER_ROOT": "/Users/xxx/flutter",
  "PUB_ENVIRONMENT": "flutter_cli:create",
  "PUB_CACHE": "/Users/xxx/flutter/.pub-cache",
}
exit code: 66
```

Comment: I've just upgraded flutter to 3.7.9 and got no issues on creating a new app. You should make sure that your current user is authorized to create files and directories in the directory that you are trying to create a new flutter app.

Comment: Are you sure about the directory where you are running the command ? Try running `flutter clean` and delete `pubspec.lock` and try runinng `flutter pub get`

Comment: I guess it is not error inside flutter app so above might not work, how about trying to  delete the `~/.pub-cache` directory in your `users/xxx/flutter` dir and then running `flutter pub get` again. Because that contains cached dart files , that might be causing the error

Comment: i think I tried all but no success. may be something with do with the installation. I am finding a doc which will help me to totally clean old install and then will do a fresh install

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the installed folder and downloaded latest version of flutter and put them in the same folder.

And then I installed the `flutter-cli` by running the command `sudo npm i -g flutter-cli`

Then I got some other error related to permission in different folder and keep giving them permission and finally the run command is working but it keep asking me permission for lot of files